# Potential auto-retag glitch with visual studio

Tags: support, tags

This could be my imagination, but way too often I come across questions tagged something like this:

> visual-studio visual

Notice that extra `visual` on the end?  I see it all the time.  I used to just ignore it or remove it by hand if I had the time, but I'm starting to wonder if that's a bug with the auto-retag script that runs in the background every hour, where it knows to retag `studio` as `visual-studio` but isn't smart enough to remove the `visual` as well.

Comment: I didn't even know we had an auto-retag working in the background. Isn't that what the whole tag synonyms proposal has been working for all this time?

Comment: If there is some automatic retagging going on, this may be caused by the new popularity ordering that was recently implemented (i.e., the auto retagging wouldn't match "studio visual" or "visual xyz1 xyz2 studio").

Comment: @Jon This has been around for a long time, but I've recently started to think of this as a bug rather than user error.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "auto-retag script that runs in the background every hour" that I know of..

Either the moderators are renaming tags globally and causing side effects, or it's user error.

Comment: I guess references to said system need to be removed from the FAQ...

Comment: There used to be.  I'll dig up a link, but it might take a while 'cause this goes back even to the uservoice days...